# Elements left and right from parent

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Is there a way of evenly distributing elements as you add them left and right from parent, with the parent in the middle?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cucc9.jpg)

Comment: should you write your base code here first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this solving your problem (using grid) ?

```css
#container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, auto);
  
  border:solid 1px black;
}
#root{
grid-column:2;
grid-row:1/1000; /* If you know the number of element you can replace 1000 by nbElement/2 */

background-color: red;
}

.element{
background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='root'>Root</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
  <div class='element'>Element</div>
</div>
```